# Remove a symlink with PHP on Windows

Tags: php, windows, symlink

How do I remove a symlink with PHP on windows?

Running this:

```
mkdir('test');
symlink('test', 'test2');
unlink('test2');
```

Gives the following error:

```
PHP Warning:  unlink(test2): Permission denied in C:\path\to\app\testlink.php on line 4
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() C:\path\to\app\testlink.php:0
PHP   2. unlink() C:\path\to\app\testlink.php:4
```

The directory and symlink were made correctly, just not removed.

Running:

- PHP 5.4.9 (CLI)
- Windows 8

Comment: Edit: Missed the "Windows" bit. Actually according to the docs, Windows DOES support it, so it should work?

Comment: The docs have a number of Windows examples, I'd give the page a read; http://php.net/manual/en/function.symlink.php

Comment: @verv like I said it does create the symlink correctly, its the `unlink` function thats not working.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out. So Ill leave this here for future reference:

To remove a symlink to a directory use the `rmdir` function:

```
mkdir('test');
symlink('test', 'test2');
rmdir('test2');
```

`unlink` is for removing files.

Comment: This only works for Windows. On *nix you still have to use unlink for symlinks, no matter what they point to.

Comment: @Tamlyn notice the question explicitly says this is a Windows issue.

Comment: sure but I thought it was worth pointing out that you have to do platform sniffing if you want your code to work cross platform. That wasn't obvious to me and I had to do some tests to find out.